# Splitting scraped data via PyQuery

Tags: python, web-scraping, pyquery

I have the following scenario:

```
<div class="entry">
<p>one</p>
<p>two<br />three<br />four</p>
<p>five<br />six</p>
</div>
```

I would like to yield `['one','two','three','four','five','six']`.

So far I have:

```
import PyQuery as pq
s = pq(html)
list = [i.text() for i in s('div.entry').find('p').items()]
```

This only breaks it into the `<p>` tags completely ignoring the `<br />` tags. I've tried the following:

```
list = [i.text() for i in s(table).find('p').find('br').items()]
list = [i.text() for i in s(table).find('p').find('br').prevAll().items()]
list = [i.split('\n') for i in s(table).find('br').replaceWith('\n')]
```

None of these have worked. Furthermore, the [PyQuery API](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/api.html) lists `.replaceWith()` as a valid function, but when I do `test = s(table).find('br').replaceWith('anytext')`, it doesn't replace it with anything and I get no errors, just the same list of items with `<br />` tags in between them. Does `.replaceWith()` treat `<br>` and `<br />` differently?

### More complex example

```
<div class="entry">
<p>122 E. Washington St.<br />
734-665-8767</p>
<p>Amadeus is offering both pricing options.</p>
<p><strong>Lunch 2 for $15 </strong><br />
Choice of:<br />
<strong>Soup<br />
Green salad </strong></p>
<p>Choice of lunch dish:<br />
<strong>1 Golabek<br />
3 Piergies<br />
3 Placeki<br />
Kielbsa<br />
Kapusta salad<br />
Warsaw salad<br />
Artichoke salad<br />
Potato salad</strong></p>
<p><strong>Lunch $15</strong><br />
Three Course Meal<br />
Choice of lunch entrée with green salad and dessert</p>
<p><strong>Dinner 2 for $28</strong></p>
<p>Choice of:<br />
<strong>Cup of soup<br />
Green salad </strong></p>
<p>Choice of entrée:<br />
<strong>2 Potato Snitzel<br />
4 Potato Placeki<br />
6 Piergis<br />
2 Golabki<br />
Bigos<br />
Grilled Kielbsa<br />
Vegetarian combo<br />
Krakow Chicken </strong>(one breast)<br />
<strong>Tilapia<br />
Cold salad</strong></p>
<p><strong>Dinner $28</strong><br />
Four Course Meal<br />
Choice of soup + green salad + Dinner Entrée + Dessert </p>
<p><strong>Sunday Brunch $15</strong><br />
```

#### Expected Result

`[122 E. Washington St','734-665-8767','Amadeus is offering both pricing options.','Lunch 2 for $15','Choice of:','Soup','Green salad','Choice of lunch dish:','1 Golabek','3 Piergies','3 Placeki','Kielbsa',' Kapusta salad','Warsaw salad','Artichoke salad','Potato salad','Lunch $15','Three Course Meal','Choice of lunch entrée with green salad and dessert','Dinner 2 for $28','Choice of:','Cup of soup','Green salad','Choice of entrée:','2 Potato Snitzel','4 Potato Placeki','6 Piergis','2 Golabki','Bigos','Grilled Kielbsa','Vegetarian combo','Krakow Chicken (one breast)','Tilapia','Cold salad','Dinner $28','Four Course Meal','Choice of soup + green salad + Dinner Entrée + Dessert','Sunday Brunch $15']`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pyquery is not behaving as expected. A workaround using `.contents()`:

```
>>> import lxml

>>> [e for ptag in s('div.entry').find('p').items()
       for e in ptag.contents()
       if isinstance(e, lxml.etree._ElementStringResult)]
['one', 'two ', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

Comment: This works for the simple example I used, but for a more complicated scenario, it does not. I've edited my OP.

Comment: What is the expected result?